# Azure Web Application - how to use both delegated and Application permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Background Information.

I would like my ASP.NET web application to use the MS Identity platform to authenicate users... and allow them to see their own profile.
This part of my code is working.  I also have a function that allows the end user to pick an file from their local computer and upload to SP via upload session via MS Graph.  This is also currently working

The security configuration I have under "API Permissions" for my Azure Application registration is as follows:

- Sites.ReadWrite.All->Delegated
- User.Read->Delegated

But now I would like to have the application itself do the file upload. So I change the security settings to look like this:

- Sites.ReadWrite.All->Application
- User.Read->Delegated

When I try to upload, I get an access denied error message returned

I also added "Files.ReadWrite.All" for the application, but that didn't work either.
Can someone point me in the right direction?  Do i have to create a separate graphClient just for the application to the upload?

**EDIT 1**

I'm wondering if this is relevant:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/354161/sitesselected-accessdenied-when-uploading-files.html

Does anyone know what the OP means when he says

> Our application is registered to have access at target site collection
> with permission role "WRITE"

Or maybe a better question is how do you do this?

Comment: Have you tried to reset the app consents (in the "Enterprise Applications")? I mean, delete the app in the "Enterprise Applications" and then re-add it. Note - this is different from the app reigstration. Maybe the old consent is stuck somewhere. Or just check what are the granted consents for you app (in azure portal)

Answer (score 0):

After assign the application type api permission to your azure ad app, you need to use `ClientCredentialFlow` to generate the access token and used it to call the api.

Then you can use the access token to send http request directly. It's an division part so it should work in your scenario.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;    

IConfidentialClientApplication app;
app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("azure_ad_app_client_id")
                        .WithClientSecret("client_secret")
                        .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tanent_name.onmicrosoft.com"))
                        .Build();
AuthenticationResult result = null;
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                        .ExecuteAsync();
string accesstoken = result.AccessToken;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Site-Selected permision in an Application Permission capacity, you need to do a few things.

1. You need to get the SharePoint site ID, which you can do by appending _api/site/id to the end of the site URL. For example, your Sharepoint site probably has a link something like https://host.sharpoint.com/sites/sitename/xxxxxxx. You want to add the _api/site/id after the /sitename/ portion of the link. This will give you a GUID, so save that in a safe place, as you will need it quite a bit.
2. Next, get the App ID from your registration.
3. More than likely, your admin will need to do this, and there's articles on this around, but the admin needs to run a powershell script that assignes the read and write permissions to the site ID, using the app registration ID.

Once that is complete, you will be able to use the Microsoft Graph client to get information about document libraries and such. For example:

```
await _graphServiceClient.Sites[siteId].Drives.Request().GetAsync();

await _graphServiceClient.Drives[drivesId].Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();
```

The first line get's you the folders in the base document library, and the second gets you the content of one of those filders, based on the driveID. Based on this, you can see how you could chain your way down a file structure.